# How can I detect when a user's session has finished logging off

Tags: c#, session, service, user-profile

I have a Windows service that is successfully detecting SessionLogon and SessionLogoff (and most of the othes) by overriding the ServiceBase object. This works well. However, it appears these events are fired immediately after authentication and immediately after the user clicks the Log off button (or some automated process logs the user off). In addition to knowing when the user first starts to log in and first starts to log out, I need to know about when the user finishes logging on and finishes logging off. I currently look for the user's shell process to start executing (typically explorer.exe) for log in and for the most part that works pretty well. By the time their shell has launched if they're using roaming profiles or other log in actions are taking place, I can pretty much be sure that by the time the shell is running that the lion's share of the log on process has occurred.

However for log off, this hasn't proven to be reliable. I'm looking for a way to accurately detect when a user's log off has finished including when all their profile information has finished being synchronized or copied and whatever other log off actions have occurred. Simply watching for their shell program to end doesn't seem to be enough as it may take from a few seconds to several minutes for log off to occur (say if they have a roaming profile).

So in short, **I'm looking for a programmatic way in C# to detect when the full log off has occurred and all profile synchronization or what have you has finished *after the SessionLogoff event* has fired.**

I've looked high and wide, but haven't seen anyone talking about the time difference between when that event occurs and when the actual log off finishes.

NOTE: I also cannot rely on the disconnect event because the user might disconnect after logoff but before their profile finishes synchronizing/copying what have you. I'm looking for a way to detect (within a few seconds of it occuring) the finished log off.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried listening to [SystemEvents.SessionEnded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionended.aspx)?

Check for [SessionEndedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.sessionendedeventargs.aspx).[Reason](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.sessionendedeventargs.reason.aspx) == [SessionEndReasons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.sessionendreasons.aspx).Logoff.

Comment: Yes. As I said to begin with, I am already successfully detecting SessionLogoff. However, that appears to occur as soon as the user clicks the log off button. There is then a period of time AFTER that event where operations are performed such as synchronizing the profile to the server which may take anywhere from a few seconds to a few minutes. I want a way to detect when the process of logging out finishes (after profile copying, etc).

Comment: Yes, I read that in your question.  You said you are detecting SessionLogoff via overriding the ServiceBase object.  The SystemEvents has two events.  The documentation on `SessionEnding` says "Occurs when the user is trying to log off or shut down the system."  This sounds like choosing the log off button.  `SessionEnded` says "Occurs when the user is logging off or shutting down the system."  This sounds like a post-logoff event.  That is why I suggested it.  Maybe you have already tried this, but it sounds like what you need.

Comment: SessionEnding gives one a chance to cancel the log off operations after the user clicks the log off button but before SessionLogoff. If no process responds to SessionEnding with Cancel == true, then SessionLogoff is fired. Both events can be thought of occurring at the beginning of the log off operation. What I'm looking for is another event or way to accurately determine that the log off and any other log off operations (specifically profile synch) has finished.